# Include Twitter share fails

Tags: php, javascript

I am struggling with including this javascript snippet into PHP code and make it work.
How can I change it to not only successfully include it but also get it to work as expected?

```
<a class="popuptweet" href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fpages%2Ftweet-button" onclick="return popitup('http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fpages%2Ftweet-button')"></a>
```

Comment: What is expected? what are you trying to achieve? I don't see any PHP here at all...

Comment: What exactly is unsuccessful right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good challenge!
What about this code? If and only if I understood your question right!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function popitup(link){
     window.showModalDialog(link, "", "dialogWidth:500px; dialogHeight:400px; center:yes"); 
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<a class=\"popuptweet\" href=\"http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fpages%2Ftweet-button\" onclick=\"return popitup('http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fpages%2Ftweet-button')\">Click Me!</a>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted Stefano. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    echo "<a class=\"popuptweet\" href=\"http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fpages%2Ftweet-button\" onclick=\"return popitup('http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fpages%2Ftweet-button')\"></a>";
?>
```

Should work. It's hard to give you more help with the small amount of information you've provided.